# How do I disable keyboard entry for a specific component in primefaces+jsf using JS/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Need to disable a primefaces extensions timePicker for user keyboard entry, as it has no default property to do that.
I tried using js/jQuery and failed. When running, the project disables all fields in the section.

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($) {
$('#ui-timepicker-div').on("keydown keypress keyup", false);}
</script>`

Is this the right way ? if not someone please suggest a solution.

Thanks !

Comment: For a start, unless you've forgotten to post some of your code, you're missing a closing brace and semi-colon. Passing $ as an argument to your function also isn't necessary, as it's already defined in the global scope, and might cause you problems.

Comment: Is this right ? 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($)) {
$('#ui-timepicker-div').on("keydown keypress keyup", false);}
</script>

Comment: No. The jquery learning center has pretty good user-friendly docs. Read up on document ready here: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ giving you the answer isn't going to help you long run...